# Delta of an option in two cases

Tags: options, volatility, greeks, delta, call

Let C be the prime of a call in fi=unction of the price  in term F, Strike K, volatilité $\sigma$ and maturity t: 
$C(F,K,\sigma,t,r) $
We assume that we know $\delta$

$\delta=\frac{\partial}{\partial F}C(F,K,\sigma,t,r)$

I would like to compute $\delta$ the variation of C in function of F in two cases :

1-If $\sigma=f(F,K)$

2-If $\sigma=g(\delta)$ 
Thanks everyone

Comment: For your second question, the delta can only be solved from a differential equation. The first one is straightforward.

Comment: Could you please explain more !

Comment: What's the expression of C ?

Comment: Please edit your question. I do not know whether you want the formula for $C$ or anything else?

Comment: For your second question, is you made up this or from a practical question, as I rarely see anything with an assumption that the volatility is a function of the delta. For FX, we can have some risk-reversal or butterfly quote, but the vol and the strikes can be correspondingly solved. That is, it  makes more sense to assume that the vol to be a function of $F$ and $K$, while the second question does not make practical sense, though may be as a mathematical exercise.

Comment: Ah, I need to have the expression of C so as to calculate the detla (the partial derivation) ?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35526/discussion-between-sino-and-gordon).